# Ajax deleting checkbox delete the first one or the previous one, not the required - jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete a category from the below html code.  When I click the previous one deletes or the first one.

--HTML CODE--

```
<div id="catlist" name="catlist" style=" color:#fff; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;">

<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_cat['cat']; ?>" class="checkboxcat" id="<?php $ctn = $row_cat['cat']; echo $ctn; ?>"  name="catcheckbox" style="border:#cccccc 1px solid; background-color:#fff;">

<span class="cattext" id="<?php echo $ctn; ?>"><?php echo $ctn; ?></span>

<span class="CatDelete" id="<?php echo $ctn; ?>" style="position:relative; left:10px; color:#c3c3c3; font-size:10px; cursor:pointer;">Delete</span>

</div>
```

--JS CODE--

```
$(".CatDelete").live('click',function() {

var valu = $('.checkboxcat').closest('input').find('checkbox').val();

var dataString = 'CatDelVal='+valu;
    $.ajax({     type: "POST",     
        url: "cat_delete.php",     
        data: dataString,     
        success: function(){       
    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);     }     });      
    return false;   


});


The issue is here: 
**var valu = $('.checkboxcat').closest('input').find('checkbox').val();**
```

When I click on delete that particular category must be deleted,  but not happening any idea why?

[update] http://jsfiddle.net/7RrNN/

Comment: Can you show an screen shot of what this looks like? Or a jsFiddle perhaps.

Comment: jsFiddle does not execute PHP code. Please create an actual HTML-only page.

Comment: @Bergi removed all php code already

Answer (score 1):

I believe your JS code should change like this: (use `on` instead `live`, as `live` is deprecated)

```
$(".CatDelete").on('click', function() {

var valu = $(this).siblings('.checkboxcat').val();

var dataString = 'CatDelVal='+valu;
    $.ajax({     type: "POST",     
        url: "cat_delete.php",     
        data: dataString,     
        success: function(){       
    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);     }     });      
    return false;   
});
```

<strike>PHP Code should also change like this I believe</strike>

```
<span class="CatDelete" id="<?php echo $ctn; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row_cat['cat']; ?>" style="position:relative; left:10px; color:#c3c3c3; font-size:10px; cursor:pointer;">Delete</span>
```

Comment: The #data-id changes for every checkbox value. The user will have to click .CatDelete for the event to trigger.

Comment: I think you can use the siblings method to locate the checkbox easily, check my updated answer.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

The next value is on the alert() not the clicked value.

Comment: What is your jQuery version? You must be having an old version of jQuery. If so please update to the latest.

Comment: @Jean, well, that wont support `on` method as it was added on 1.7, Is there any particular reason why you are still using 1.4? Can't you upgrade it to the new versions 1.8.* ?

Comment: @Jean, in case you can't upgrade to a newer jQuery, replace `on` with `bind`

Answer (score 1):

You have three elements with the same id on your page, which is invalid - an `ID` must be unique.

Not sure what `$('.checkboxcat').closest('input').find('checkbox')` was supposed to do, but: There's hardly any element *inside* an `<input>`, so you won't need to get the closest input parent element. Also, there are no `<checkbox>` elements in HTML. Did you mean the following?

```
$('input:checkbox.checkboxcat')
```

Comment: I used `valu = $('input:checkbox.checkboxcat').val();`  
If the checkbox has values 1,2,3 and I click on 1 it deletes 2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time.  I have no idea why it was not working.  I just recoded and it worked fine. Probably the simplicity was the idea. not sure.